# TYPO3: Pass current menu page uid as parameter to userFunc

Tags: function, menu, parameters, typoscript

How can I pass menu pages ids to a custom user function?
I need it so that I can change some page links which are not valid in TYPO3.
They will be parsed in another application.

```
lib.test = HMENU
lib.test {
  ...
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO = 1
    NO {
        # do not create a link here else there are double <a> tags
        doNotLinkIt = 1
        stdWrap.cObject = CASE
        stdWrap.cObject {
            key.field = doktype
            default = TEXT
            default {
                field = nav_title // title
                typolink.parameter.field = uid
                typolink.wrap = |<span><strong></strong></span>
                typolink.ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1

                postUserFunc = user_productsOnCurrentPage->main
                postUserFunc {
                    // not working
                    pageId.data = {page:uid}
                    pageId.insertData = 1

                    // also not working
                    pageId.field = uid 
                }
            }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could access the page ID directly in the user function:

TypoScript:

```
typolink.userFunc = user_mcfazabosOnCurrentPage->main
```

PHP:

```
$pageId = $this->cObj->getFieldVal( 'uid' );
```

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/DataTypes/Gettext/Index.html) might have a solution to your problem:

> In *TMENU* $cObj->data is set to the page-record for each menu item.

So to pass the page uid of the "current iteration" of hmenu this should do:

```
postUserFunc.pageId.data = field:uid
```

credit to [this](http://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/95596/) (german) thread.